# Use parts of AJAX response in different divs

Tags: php, ajax

I want to send this AJAX request:

```
function sumMonthly() {
var cur_month = $('#month option:selected').attr("value");

var request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'inc/functions.php',
    data: {action: ["get_sum_income", "get_sum_expense", "get_cash_remaining"], cur_month:cur_month}
});
request.done(function(response){
    $('#sum_income').html('<h1 class="positiveNum float-right">&#36;' + response.get_sum_income + '</h1>');
    $('#sum_expense').html('<h1 class="float-right">&#36;' + response.get_sum_expense + '</h1>');
});
request.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus){
    alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
});
};
```

and somehow access the return response, but I'm not sure how to access only a certain part of the response and put it in one div, then put another part in another div.  Here's some of my PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && in_array("get_sum_income", $_POST['action'])) {   

//do stuff here, put result in $i;


if(!empty($i)) {
    echo $i;
} else {
    echo '&#36;0.00';
};

};
```

Comment: So I assume $i is a json array. Is it a multiple line array or just a single line? If it's a multiple line, you need to parse the json data with an .each function. If it's a single line, then you can just use $('#divname').text(response.variablename); etc. Perhaps you can provide us more info.

Comment: no its not a json array.  its a single value from an array.  Do i need to use json_encode?  Also, the php code above is only one of multiple code blocks that all echo $i or maybe they need to echo different variables, but the point is that when its all said and done, $i is a single number, but the ajax response should include multiple, individual numbers. I want to access each of these individual numbers and put them in separate divs.

Comment: Utilize json_encode for this purpose, that's why it's there.

Comment: I get undefined, and if i add dataType: "json" i get a parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a real "answer" to your problem, but I can't write what I want in a comment.

You'll need to work on your PHP to consolidate the code and make an array something like this:

```
$json = array
             (
               'varname1' => $variable1,
               'varname2' => $variable2,
               'varname3' => $variable3,
               'varname4' => $variable4,
               'varname5' => $variable5
              );
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Then on client side you can do something like:

```
.done(function(response) {
       $('#div1').text(response.varname1);
       $('#div2').text(response.varname2);
       $('#div3').text(response.varname3);
       $('#div4').text(response.varname4);
       $('#div5').text(response.varname5);
                          });
```

Again, this is not a specific solution, but it should get you started.

I always write my php, then run it without the client, grab the output on the screen and submit it to jsonlint.com to make sure it's json.

Comment: this was enormously helpful.  I will be able to refactor my entire application and make it much more efficient.  thank you!